# Linq order by not working on DateTime after group by into anonymous object

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

Note: ThisDate is nullable.
Trying to get a list of strings for a drop down list ordered like so:

```
2023 March
2023 February 
2023 January
```

And so on.

My query:

```cs
ThisDateList = await ctx.Table1
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.ThisDate)
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.ThisDate.Value.Year, i.ThisDate.Value.Month})
    .Select(g => g.Key.Year.ToString() + " " + DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.GetMonthName(g.Key.Month))
    .Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();
```

But they don't get ordered the way I expected them to. Thanks.

Comment: _But they don't get ordered the way I expected them to._ Please, provide an example of input, expected output and what output you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
ThisDateList = await ctx.Table1
    .Select(i => new { i.ThisDate.Value.Year, i.ThisDate.Value.Month })
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Year)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Month)
    .Select(x => x.Year.ToString() + " " + DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.GetMonthName(x.Month))
    .ToListAsync();
```